# Unable to launch the uiautomatorviewer.bat

Tags: appium

I'm facing the below issue while launching the uiautomatorviewer.bat.

In my laptop I have both 32 bit and 64 bit JVMs. But I have setting to use only 64 bit JVM. Still I'm facing this issue.

Could you please help on the same.

[image]
[image]